# Make the serial downvoting reversal script more active

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

From time to time I get serially downvoted. I wait for the reversal script to kick in, and it doesn't, and when I flag it, nothing happens.

It's not because the serial downvoting didn't happen, but because they can't [do much about it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/511?m=25691017#25691017).

> Actually, I don't even know :-) I asked a Stack Exchange employee to look, but vote information is private and I can't look at it myself
>
> ...
>
> That's all moderators can do with serial voting, really. We bring it to the attention of Stack Exchange employees if need be, and then they decide if anything needs to be done.

Fine. In that case, just make the serial downvoting script more active. Scripts can know who did what without any privacy issues.

Comment: It's certainly not the case that we "can't be bothered doing anything about it".  The day you flagged yourself for receiving two downvotes, [you received two downvotes 66 minutes apart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1UvyO.png).  I thought you were referring to those, which is why I wrote that reply.  You left another flag clarifying which two posts you meant later on.  Why would you take things like this out of context and say our responses "have no relationship with reality"?  Why pretend we're acting in bad faith?  It seems unkind.

Comment: @snailboat "you left another flag clarifying which two posts you meant" - which got marked as declined, not even as helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no evidence that this *is* serial downvoting.

I wanted to review the two of your posts that got downvoted, in order to give some feedback if possible, and started by looking at your profile, when I realized that you have [*a lot* of questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/91/andrew-grimm?tab=questions).

Two downvotes, even in quick succession, could very well be a coincidence, and by two completely unrelated users. Then, if it were the case that one user issued both downvotes, two downvotes wouldn't count as "serial downvoting" by my definition.

**Perhaps we should start by clarifying what the definition of "serial downvoting" is.**

---

Without a clear understanding of what does and what doesn't count as "serial downvoting", **I can't agree with this feature request**.

---

FYI ([source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijw9qLhvvKAhXB6KYKHWycAFAQFgglMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSerial_killer&usg=AFQjCNGpMYnKX1n4fU3qAi-L18oWpqh0IA&sig2=lVux0n9qvZdsUocK_oHFuw)):

> A serial killer is a person who murders **three or more** people, usually due to abnormal psychological gratification, with the murders taking place over more than a month and including a significant break (a "cooling off period") between them.